# Not able to select Menu items in NASPT Exerciser using pywinauto

Tags: python-2.7, ui-automation, autoit, pywinauto

I am using **pywinauto** to automate NASPT Exerciser tool.
[image: I am not able to select the configure ans Reset . But I am getting all other buttons to click such as PhotoAlbum .... And neither I am able to click "all".]

```
 app.IntelNASPerformanceToolkitExerciser.PhotoAlbum.Click().
```

to click photo album button,

```
app.IntelNASPerformanceToolkitExerciser.all.Click()
```

to click all. It's not selecting all buttons.

```
app.IntelNASPerformanceToolkitExerciser.MenuSelect("Configure->NASPT Tool")
```

It is throwing error saying can't select Menu to this object.

Is there any other way to achieve above problem?
Can anyone help about this?

Comment: "Configure" looks like toolbar button. There is no menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is .NET application. `pywinauto` has very limited support of .NET controls. So you need to use Windows UI Automation API for such toolbar. Precisely `InvokePattern` should help with pressing toolbar button.

Or you may try to click button by hard coded coordinates like that:

```
app.IntelNASPerformanceToolkitExerciser.Children()[54].ClickInput(coords=(300, 10))
```

This hard-coding way may be better than dealing with quite complicated UI Automation API.

BTW, you may get [pywinauto clone with .NET programmatic names support](https://code.google.com/r/pjquirk-dotnetnames/source/browse/). Just download it as zip and run `python setup.py install`.
With that mod you can code so:

```
app.IntelNASPerformanceToolkitExerciser.toolStrip.ClickInput(coords=(300, 10))
```

I've just checked it. I think hard-coded coordinates is OK here because the software is end-of-lifed and will not be changed. There are not so many unsupported .NET controls.

Comment: "Configure","Reset " are in toolstrip and they are static. I guess pywinauto does not support static controls

Comment: pywinauto supports control with "Static" type. It's called "Label" in .NET.
Toolstrip is visible to Win32 API as one window, so pywinauto cannot recognize separate buttons.

Comment: Just downloaded .NET programmatic names. It worked like charm !!